# System of quadratic equations with parameter

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'd appreciate your help with this problem:

$p - a^2 = b$

$p - b^2 = c$

$p - c^2 = d$

$p - d^2 = a$

Where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real numbers, $p$ is a real parameter lower or equal to 1 and greater or equal to 0.

Thank you a lot. I am capable of solving the problem for positive numbers, but that's it. :(

Answer (score 2):

- Subtracting two adjacent equations,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    (a-b)(a+b) &=& c-b \\
    (b-c)(b+c) &=& d-c \\
    (c-d)(c+d) &=& a-d \\
    (d-a)(d+a) &=& b-a
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Note that
$$a=b \iff b=c \iff c=d \iff a=d$$

Now
$$a^2+a-p=0$$

> $$a=b=c=d=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4p}}{2}$$

---

- Subtracting alternate equations, $$
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      (a-c)(a+c) &=& d-b \\
      (b-d)(b+d) &=& a-c
    \end{array}
  \right.$$

Note that
$$a=c \iff b=d$$
$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    p-a^2 &=& b \\
    p-b^2 &=& a
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Now
$$p-(p-a^2)^2=a$$

$$p^2-(2a^2+1)p+(a^4+a)=0$$

$$(a^2+a-p)(a^2-a+1-p)=0$$

Since $a^2+a-p=0$ reproduces the previous case, we only need to solve

$$a^2-a+1-p=0$$

> $$a=c=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{4p-3}}{2}$$
>
> $$b=d=\frac{1\mp \sqrt{4p-3}}{2}$$

---

- For distinct $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, that'll be a solution of $12$-th order polynomial equations in terms of $p$.

**P.S.**

$a,b,c,d$ are critical points of the iteration $u_{n+1}=p-u_{n}^2$ of period $4$.

Comment: A little correction: In your first "yellow zone", it is $a=b=c=d=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4p}}{2}$ (with a minus sign in front of 1).

Comment: Edited, many thanks!